# Using tooltip with click instead of hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip, qtip

Is there a way to get a javascript tooltip do only display if you click on an element rather than simply hovering the mouse over it?

I have

```
    var selection = canvas.selectAll("circle").data(data);

selection.enter().append("circle")

canvas.append("svg:circle")

    selection
      .attr("title", my qtip stuff)
      .on("click", function(d, i){
          /*How to make qtip show up here*/
       })
```

Comment: Post your existing code, give more context - for example, what framework/plugin you are using etc...

Answer (score 2):

Since your code block mentions `qtip`, I'm assuming you're using the [qTip jQuery plugin](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/).

When you call `.qtip()` you can specify which events will activate it, like so:

```
$(your_selector).qtip({
    show: 'click',
    hide: 'click'
});
```